# Why does React.useCallback trigger rerender, thouh it should not?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have redux connected Component with onClick action bound to it. Every time I click it rerenders, though I use `useCallback` hook. Here is my simplified component:

```
const Map = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // from react-redux
  const coordinates = useSelector(state => state.track.coordinates); // from react-redux
  const onClick = useCallback( // from react
    data => {
      return dispatch({type: 'ADD_COORDINATES', payload: data});
    },
    [dispatch]
  );

  return (
    <div className="Map">
      <GoogleMap
        onClick={onClick}>
        <Track
          coordinates={coordinates}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: In addition to my answer, you should explain how you know your components re-renders, how you checked it, and adding a producible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've improved code sample. I'm sure that component rerenders because I see console.log outputs and network requests from children.

Comment: Well, it obviously renders because of the selector, why you except it not to render? (Check updated answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without giving any additional context, and that the component is really "simplified" (there is nothing else that may cause a render), `Map` component will re-render only on its parent render:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const coordinates = useSelector(coordinatesSelector);
  return <Map />;
};
```

On dispatching `addCoordinates` action you may trigger its parent.

You should try and [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) the `Map` component:

> If your function component renders the same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

```
 const Map = () => {
  ...
  return ....;
};

export default React.memo(Map);
```

---

Edit after question update:

Your component re-renders due to `useSelector` as [stated in the docs:](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#useselector)

> When an action is dispatched, useSelector() will do a reference comparison of the previous selector result value and the current result value. If they are different, the component will be forced to re-render. If they are the same, the component will not re-render.

Therefore, you might want to add additional `equalityFn`:

```
const coordinates = useSelector(state => state.track.coordinates, areSameCoords)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed problem by adding React.memo to the GoogleMap component. React.memo didn't prevent parent component updates.